# What does the italic "f" in a React props method using React Dev Tools mean?

Tags: reactjs, methods, react-devtools

[image: React Dev Tools Snapshot]

What does the "f" mean? I'm having trouble using the method in other components and I'm assuming this f means something important?

Comment: Hover it. "f" means function.

Comment: Nothing pops up when I hover? Maybe it's ok, but I'm working on a tutorial, the instructor's dev tools don't show the "f", but I just disregarded it. Now the method isn't showing up in another component I added it to? Weird.